# Element is not clickable with files and selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, file, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
def enter_credentials(self):

    path = "student_credentials.txt"
    if os.path.getsize(path) == 0:
        input_email = input("Enter email address: ")
        input_password = input("Enter password: ")
        z = open("student_credentials.txt", "w")
        z.write(input_email + "\n" + input_password)
        z.close()
        new_creds = [input_email, input_password]
        return new_creds
    else:
        z = open("student_credentials.txt", "r")
        creds = z.readlines()
        z.close()
        return creds

def validate_credentials(self, credentials):  # Enter the email and password


    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, google_login_button))).click()  # Clicking on the 'Sign In with Google' button
    print("Executed!")


    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, emailTextBox))).send_keys(credentials[0])  # Entering the email address

# The problem occurs here
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
    print("Executed!")

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, passwordTextBox))).send_keys(credentials[1])  # Entering the password
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
    print("Executed!")
```

If `student_credentials.txt` is empty, it will ask the user to input the email and password and it is stored in the file and `new_creds`.

If the credentials are already in the `student_credentials.txt`, email and password are stored in `creds`.

Both of which are returned.

In `validate_credentials`, the returned value from the previous function containing email and password are sent to the selenium commands.

When I am not using files and simply enter the credentials, the code is working perfectly fine.

When I am trying to incorporate files into this, I am getting this error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="VfPpkd-RLmnJb"> is not clickable at point (786,527) because another element <div class="ANuIbb IdAqtf"> obscures it`

The stack trace shows this code line: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()` (The first one)

I followed questions based on `not clickable` but I didn't get a proper answer.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It explains exactly why the click didn't work. This has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC I wanted to know what is the relationship between the files and the element not being clickable. If I remove the file part, the code is working but when I try to add files, it is showing this error. As I mentioned, I read questions based on this but it is of no use.

Comment: @RavuriPraneeth what you are asking really seems like a question about your app itself. Whatever the element `<div class="ANuIbb IdAqtf">` is, it physically obscures the element you are trying to click, so you probably need to figure out what that is and how to make it go away.

Comment: C. Peck is pointing you at the same thing I was... the error message. If I were to guess, your `credentials[0]` is empty or invalid in some way and the popup is an error message or something telling you of the problem. Have you watched the script run?